# Why is 'Authenticated' only sometimes added to the users_roles table?

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

I understand as a default drupal does not include a row in the users_roles table for role 2 (Authenticated User), but it appears that sometimes it does, and I can't understand any rhyme or reason to it.

My drupal site authenticates through ldap, but I haven't set up any additional groups or other automated processes for assigning roles.

Comment: Do you have logintobogan module?